# Windows minizing and other animations not working in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, animations

I am using ubuntu 18.04. Everything, including animations was working fine on my ubuntu. Then, I had to blacklist the nouveau driver and install nvidia graphics driver. Ever since then, animations don't work. I tried doing the same thing on a few other systems also, and on all the systems, animations stop working after blacklisting nouveau driver and installing nvidia driver.

[Attaching the output of nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMia9.png)

Comment: I do suffer from the same issue after installing nvidia driver.

Comment: Can you add the output of the command `nvidia-smi` to your question?

Comment: @AbdallaArbab added a screenshot of the output

Comment: From what I see everything had to do with the installation is fine. You just need to configure your system to work with Nvidia driver. It should show up like in this image: `https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*V-XQAFD7TbyS4rV1DASYoA.png`. BTW what does this command show you `nvidia-settings`.