# Missing animations

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments, .desktop, animations

I have just installed the Ubuntu 18.04.4 (actually few times already) and I still find all of the animations missing. The Ubuntu has disabled them right after install, or they disappear after a while. I have checked tweaks, it says the animations are on, but they simply are not showing. Anyway I cannot figure out how to turn them on, so if anyone could help me I would be very glad. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TfQM7LLuda53tB7uGSenBn-10hiLXOQQ

Comment: Simply, there are no animations. No animations for opening/closing/switching desktops/opening app drawer or literally anything

Comment: I am aware of fact that there is the button "show applications". But I am talking of missing animations, like scaling the window of a program

Answer (score 0):

If animations still do not work, than probably you have problems with graphics driver.

To install Nvidia driver you could use [this question answers](https://askubuntu.com/q/1077061/925971). You need to know your driver version. It could be different.

The information about it you could find in comments to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165663/925971).